# XmlPullParser пропускает теги

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlparser

XmlPullParser пропускает теги. Вот например дана такая структура xml файла:

```
           <Days>
                    <Name>1</Name>
                    <Weeks>
                       <string/>
                       <string/>
                       <string/>
                    </Weeks>

                    <Name>2</Name>
                    <Weeks>
                       <string/>
                       <string/>
                       <string>Иванов И-12</string>
                    </Weeks>
                 </Hour>
           <Days>
```

и вот сам код:

```
public class PullParser {
final String LOG_TAG = "myLog";
String xml;


    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    String tagName = "";
    String per = "";

public PullParser(String xml) {
    this.xml = xml;
}

public void parser(){
    boolean exit = false;
    try {
        XmlPullParser xpp = prepareXpp();
        while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !exit ) {

            switch (xpp.getEventType()) {

                // начало тега
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                    if (xpp.isEmptyElementTag()) {
                        per = "empty";
                    }

                    else if (xpp.getName().equals("Day")) {
                        tagName = "Day";
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equals("string")) {
                        tagName = "string";
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equals("Weeks")) {
                        tagName = "Weeks";
                    }

                    break;
                // конец тега
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                    if (xpp.getName().equals("Day") ||
                            xpp.getName().equals("string") ||
                            xpp.getName().equals("Name") ||
                            xpp.getName().equals("weeks")) {
                        tagName = "";
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equals("Days")) {
                        exit = true;
                    }
                    break;
                // содержимое тега
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                    if (tagName.equals("string")) {
                         //  Log.d(LOG_TAG, xpp.getText());
                        list.add(xpp.getText());
                    }else if (per.equals("empty")){
                            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "PUSTO");
                        list.add("PUSTO");
                        per = "";

                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    XmlPullParser prepareXpp() throws XmlPullParserException {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    xpp.setInput(new StringReader(xml));

    return xpp;
```

При вышеописанной структуре xml файла XmlPullParser парсит правильно, вот ответ:

```
PUSTO
PUSTO
PUSTO
PUSTO
PUSTO
Иванов И-12
```

если изменить структуру xml файла на такую(в одну строку):

```
<Days><Name>1</Name><Weeks><string /><string /><string /></Weeks><Name>2</Name><Weeks><string /><string /><string>Иванов И-12 </string></Weeks></Days>
```

то ответ получается такой:

```
PUSTO
Иванов И-12
```

Вопрос, почему так происходит, и как эту проблемку решить?